# How do I print a single matrix from the code attached

Tags: r

The following code is returning 4 matrices -

```
n <- 5
for(i in range(n)){
  square_n = n*n
    for (j in range(n)){
      str1 = matrix(1:square_n, byrow=TRUE, nrow=n)
    print(str1)
    }
}
```

However when when I move the print(str1) "outside" the loop, it prints just one matrix (which is what I want). However what I'm doing calls for the print statement to be inside the loop. How do I correct my code.

Comment: Are you coming from python? This doesn't look like very R-like code. Note that `range(n)` in R might not return what you want. Perhaps you want `seq.int(n)`. Also, depending on what you want, we probably wouldn't use `for` loops in R either. A simple `lapply()` might be just what you need. It would be helpful if you actually provided the desired output so possible solutions can be tested and verified.

Answer (score 1):

It is just updating the 'str1' on each iteration and the value we get is from the last iteration.  `print` is just printing the value on the console on each iteration.  If we want to store it, then have to create a `list`

```
str1 <- vector('list', 5)
```

Inside the loop, change the assignment line to

```
str1[[i]] <- matrix(1:square_n, byrow = TRUE, nrow = n)
print(str1[[i]])
```

-full code

```
for(i in range(n)){
  square_n = n*n
    for (j in range(n)){
      str1[[i]] = matrix(1:square_n, byrow = TRUE, nrow = n)
    print(str1[[i]])
    }
}
```